# Error running: Project has no JDK configured in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings

When I try to execute program ergo, it gives me an error.

**Error running: Project has no JDK configured**

Can anybody help me? I'm newbie in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: It is because you have not configured the jdk. You may check this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/defining-a-jdk-and-a-mobile-sdk-in-intellij-idea.html?origin=old_help

Comment: @ElhamKohestani thanks a ton!!

Comment: Is your problem solved now ?

Comment: Not yet!!! Have I need to install JDK first? @ElhamKohestani

Comment: @ElhamKohestani still i've problem.

Comment: what is it? did you follow the steps mentioned in that link ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38018575/error-module-not-specified-intellij-idea-ultimate]

Comment: look i have posted again this question... @ElhamKohestani

Answer (score 25):

1) Open `Project Structure` present under `File` menu or use shortcut  `ctrl+alt+shift+S`

2) `SDKs` is located under `Platform Settings`. Select it and click the green + up the top of the window.

3) Set JDK home directory path (e.g.: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64) and click on `Apply` and `OK`.

You should be able to execute your program now.

[image]

Comment: Yes, if IDEA already selected what you want, just re-select it.

Comment: Yes, this answer solve my question.

Answer (score 5):

First, close IDE and follow this step:

> **1.** You can delete these folders in the project structure:

```
.gradle
.idea
build
```

> **2.** Then open IDE and reimport the project.
> Hopefully resolved !!

Answer (score 3):

open File -> Project Structure, under project SDK, where it says **no JDK** select dropdown and check if they are any JDKs available, select available JDK then click Apply then OK, your project should run now.