# Error: Module not specified (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, settings

I was trying to execute a simple program in IntelliJ IDEA as a static web project. I'm newbie and I'm learning web development with Node.js. I took help from the official website of IntelliJ IDEA, but the error was same. Though, I configured the settings and Project structure also.

Error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain ""
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[Snapshot of IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Q7c.jpg)

Please help me to sort out this problem. I'm digging out this problem since few days.

Comment: this time I think there is no problem with configuring IDE.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This is because the `className` value which you are passing as argument for
 `forName(String className)` method is not found or doesn't exists, or you a re passing the wrong value as the class name. Here is also a link which could help you.
**1.**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html

**2.**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

**Update**

```
Module not specified
```

According to the snapshot you have provided this problem is because you have not determined the app module of your project, so I suggest you to choose the app module from configuration. For example:

[image]

Comment: ok... module not specified what was that? I'm learning from this [tutorials of node.js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u-j7uqU7sI)

Comment: I provided an update check it I hope it may help you

Comment: Somehow I'm making mistakes... Thanks a ton!! :)

Comment: In the module classpath, I don't get the option... why?

Comment: That maybe because of renaming the project, but I am not sure. Have you renamed your project?

Comment: The blunder I was doing i.e: I hadn't installed the plugins. If anyone uses IntelliJ IDEA ultimate, you've to installed plugins otherwise download Webstorm. Webstorm doesn't need plugins. [Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-u-j7uqU7sI&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_&index=1) for easy way to understand Node.js. :)

Comment: Thanks a ton Elham... :)

Comment: You are welcome. I hadn't known that you have not installed the plugin anyway good to know that you have found the solution.:)

Answer (score 22):

this is how I fix this issue
1.open my project structure

2.click module
[image]
3.click plus button
[image]
4.click import module，and find the module's pom
[image]
5.make sure you select the module you want to import,then next next finish:)
[image]

Comment: I don't have a pom.xml file in my project, is there a way to generate it?

Comment: you may can add it by yourself,read this maven introduction know more about maven
https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html. send me email if you still dont understand : hanz27124@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4 (Ultimate Edition), the following worked for me:

1. Find the Environment variables for your project.
2. Specify, from the dropdowns, the values of "Use class path of module:" and "JRE" as in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact issue of module not found and solved it by navigating to pom.xml file in file system of my project and opening it as a maven project in my intelliJIdea.

Then it has populated the sub modules for selection in the edit configurations window.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. To solve it,

- I had to [download and install the latest version of gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html) using the comand line. `$ sdk install gradle` using the package manager or `$ brew install gradle` for mac. You might need to first [install brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553442/install-homebrew-in-a-mac) if not yet.
- Then I cleaned the project and restarted android studio and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I started to work with a colleque's project.

He was using jdk 12.0.2 .

If you are suspicious jdk difference might be the case (Your IDE complains about SDK, JDK etc.):

1. Download the appropriate jdk
2. Move new jdk to the folder of your choice. (I use C:\Program Files\Java)
3. On Intellij, click to the dropdown on top middle bar. Click Edit Configurations. Change jdk.
4. File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.