# Install Homebrew in a Mac

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, homebrew, macos-sierra

I am trying to install Homebrew in a Mac v 10.12.2 using

```
brew install node
```

But I got these errors:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: https://brew.sh/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1-First, install Homebrew.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

2-Then run brew update to make sure Homebrew is up to date.

```
brew update
```

3-As a safe measure you should run brew doctor to make sure your system is ready to brew. Run the command below and follow any recommendations from brew doctor.

```
brew doctor
```

4-Next, add Homebrew's location to your $PATH in your .bash_profile or .zshrc file.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

5-Next, install Node (npm will be installed with Node):

```
brew install node
```

6-To test out your Node and npm install, try installing Grunt (you might be asked to run with sudo):

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Comment: Solved my problem, and saved many hours frustration.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Solved my problem after several hours of trying.

Comment: If I may add -- for Apple Silicon Macs, that path should be 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"'