# "Error running 'MainKt': No JDK specified" - Kotlin - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, sdk

I am a beginner (I started today) following a YouTube tutorial on how to get started using Kotlin. My end goal is to be able to create an Android app with Kotlin independently. I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2. I have a basic "Hello World" script

[image]

that should've worked as in the video but I keep running into the same error:

[image]

I have tried changing the Module SDK in Project Structure settings with no such luck:

[image]

[image]

I have no idea of what else to do so these are the only solutions I have found and the same error occurs.

Comment: You need to install a JDK and select it instead of the Kotlin SDK. See [Error running: Project has no JDK configured in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900005/error-running-project-has-no-jdk-configured-in-intellij-idea-ultimate)

Comment: See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#set-up-jdk on how to setup JDK for your project

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run as a kotlin/native app?

If you are, then you don't need or want a Java JDK and the configuration you've shown more or less looks okay.  Obviously, you do need an JDK if your using koltin/jvm. On android, you will need a JDK.

I had the same problem, when using IntelliJ running a kotlin/native app. The error would occur when I tried to run or debug the app using a RUN/Debug configuration.  The Kotlin documentation for running a Kotlin/native app seems to indicate that this should work, but I've been getting the same error as billyBob gets.  What I did discover was that I could build the kotlin/native app and execute it from a terminal shell:

```
  .\build\bin\native\debugExecutable\KotlinNativeTemplate.exe
```

Where KotlinNativeTemplate is the project's name.  That worked and gave me the output I was expecting.  At this time, it's not clear if you can run or debug a kotlin/native app from a Run/Debug configuration.

The reason I'm going down this path of explanation is that you made the statement that you want to "create an Android app with Kotlin independently". It's not necessarily clear what your expectation is.  What I read into that is that you want to write a Kotlin Multiplatform app that targets android.  If that's the case, you'll need to install the Kotlin Multiplatform plugin and go down that path.  Please note that android application don't being at main, but rather at the Activity.onCreate method.

Comment: I believe the reason that one can't do a run/debug session is because you need to have the native code plugin added to your Intellij IDEA.  Unfortunately, this plugin is not available  in the  Community Edition.  My guess is if you have that plugin installed one would be able to add a run/debug configuration for native code. WIthout it, I think you're limited to only running or debugging VM based applications from the IDEA.  I'm using the Community Edition, so I can't verify the truth of this comment .  If you make an Android targeted multiproject app, you'll be able to run or debug that.